# Apache Beam Unbounded data processing and compute aggregations like count, durations per key per window

Tags: apache-beam

I am new to beam pipeline and I have a requirement to compute aggregated stats (counts and duration for each window - like very 30 min or so) from the events received through a Kafka topic (unbounded source).

**Events**

```
 {"id":"xxxxx", "state": "start", "timestamp": 1625718600000, "device": "device-1", ...}
 {"id":"xxxxx", "state": "end", "timestamp": 1625721300000, "device": "device-1",. ..}
 {"id":"yyyyy", "state": "start", "timestamp": 1625718600000, "device": "device-2", ...}
 {"id":"yyyyy", "state": "end", "timestamp": 1625719500000, "device": "device-2", ...}
```

*Event "xxxxx" started 10:00 and ended 10:45*

*Event "yyyyy" started 10:00 and ended 10:15*

**Expected Stats from pipeline**

```
Device    Interval       Count    Duration
device-1  10:00-10:30    1        30 min
device-2  10:00-10:30    1        15 min
device-1  10:30-11:00    0        15 min
```

I played with fixed-windows, triggers, groupByKey, CombineFn etc and I am successful in computing the aggregated counters, increment the count if the event state is *"start"* but, I am clueless on computing the overlapping window duration even with the state-full processing.

*Note: Used event identifier while grouping the events.*

Please advice me on this.

Answer (score 0):

So sounds like what you need to do is compute the start and end events at the same worker to compute the difference, right ?

I can think of few ways to do this.

- Use `GroupByKey` - you can set even ID to the key and perform a `GroupByKey` to group events based on the key and compute and output the difference.
- `Stateful DoFn` - When you receive events, store them in state keyed by the ID and when you store check for the availability of another event and compute the difference.

One thing to note that it's possible for start and end events to fall in two different Windows. Either of above solutions will not work in this case since different Windows are computed differently. I think you'll have to adapt the pipeline to account for such (rare ?) occurrences.